# Changing inline style 'background-image' with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a loop which populates a ul with li's.

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 74; i++) {
      $('#imgList').append('<li><a href="#"><img src="/default-image"/></a></li>');
      }
```

Then I have a function which changes the li > img

```
<li><a href="#"><img src="/img/default-image.png"/></a></li>
```

to li > a

```
<li style="width: 120px; height: 120px;"><a href="#" style="cursor: default; background-image: url(/new-image.png);"></a></li>
```

Now I want to push new images to it.  I have

```
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

imgs[i].src = newImages[count];
```

But the var imgs won't select the img tag as the function changes it to an a with inline background-image.  How would I select the li > a and change the background image in the inline css?

Comment: you can do `$('a').each(function(){ $(this).css('background-image', newImage); });`

Comment: Why aren't you doing all of this in one step instead of 3?

Comment: I am fetching data externally from an api, therefore if I populate the li's at step one it won't be able to fetch the data in time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('a').each(function(){ this.style.backgroundImage = newImage; });
```

*Edit: Sushil has already answered this in the comments*